# Symfony 2.3 Composer Requested Package Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I receive the following error every time I try to run composer update:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>      - The requested package doctrine/data-fixtures dev-master could not be found.
>
> Problem 2
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle dev-master could not be found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>     see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "htdocs",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

I just want to install data fixtures. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, I copy & pasted your composer.json and did a "composer install" and it completed with no issues.

My recommendation would be to make sure that composer is up-to-date (run "composer self-update") and then maybe try to clear the composer repository cache. There used to be an issue with cached repositories reporting that branches do not exist but supposedly it was fixed..

To clear the composer cache (adapted from the comment below):

> on a *nix box and have composer installed locally then it should in ".composer/cache" in your home directory.

On a *Nix system with a Local composer: remove the `~/.composer/cache` directory.

Comment: I get same issue:  Problem 1
    - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle dev-master could not be found.

Comment: Well.. since my guess didn't work, I'll try to set up an actual project real quick and see what's going on.

Comment: Strange, I copy & pasted your composer.json and did a "composer install" and it completed with no issues.

Comment: My recommendation would be to make sure that composer is up-to-date and then maybe try to clear the composer repository cache.  There used to be an issue with cached repositories reporting that branches do not exist but supposedly it was fixed...

Comment: Depends on what OS and how you have composer installed.  If you're on a *nix box and have composer installed locally then it should in ".composer/cache" in your home directory.  Not 100% sure where it goes when it's a global install but it looks like it still goes into the user home directory.